# Which increases more quickly in the expression $\frac{n^5+\cos(n)}{2-6^n}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I've read other answers regarding sequence limits, but it's not clear to me whether a finite value to the $n$th power, or $n$ to some finite power, would increase faster as $n$ approaches infinity.

Comment: For $n=6$ which is greater: $6^5$ or $6^6$?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: I think we can safely say that when $n$ is large, $\cos n$ in the numerator and $+2$ in the denominator are trivial and can safely be dropped.  Now, consider $\frac {(n+1)^5}{n^5}$ and compare that to $\frac {6^{n+1}}{6^n}$ Is the numerator growing faster than the denominator or is the denominator growing faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide the numerator and denominator by the leading term in the denominator ($6^n$): $$\frac{6^{-n}n^5+6^{-n}\cos{n}}{2^{1-n}\times3^{-n}-1}$$

The limits of individual terms can be calculated:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}6^{-n}n^5=0 \\ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}6^{-n}\cos{n}=0 \\ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}2^{1-n}=0 \\ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}3^{-n}=0$$

Then we have $$\frac{0+0}{0\times0-1} = \frac{0}{1} = 0$$